# When is the format width required, avoid MissingFormatWidthException

Tags: java, format

When using java.util.Formatter with what flags and conversions do you have to
provide the width?

I know for sure this throws a MFWE:

```
double count = -34.45;
System.out.printf("%1$0(f",count);
```

in what other cases do you have to provide the wdith and what specifically makes that necessary. Is it the f conversion? the 0 flag ?

Comment: Look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), search for `MissingFormatWidthException` and find the two cases in which a width is required or else it will throw this exception.

Comment: I couldn't find it on there

Answer (score 1):

When using the flags "-" and "0" with java.util.formatter you must specify the 
width or you will get a MissingFormatWidthException